# Code designer to better maintenance codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

currently i'm using codeigniter then i see that can use the library db in 2 styles

```
$result =  $this->db->select($id)
                    ->select($field)
                    ->get('user');
```

and like this

```
$this->db->select($id)
$this->db->select($field)
$result = $this->db->get('user');
```

to a better designer which style is better, exist some pattern between developers php codeigniter

Comment: Both methods does same work,and there is no difference between them,its all upto you which you feel good you can use :)

Comment: That's method chaining. Nothing special.

Comment: There's no difference, really. If you're working on a project on your own, do whichever you prefer. If you're in a team, decide between you and stick to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Best way. Its all about your practice.
There are  **3 Methods** to code

**Method 01**

```
$result =  $this->db->select($id)
           ->select($field)
           ->get('user');
```

**Method 02**

```
$this->db->select($id)
$this->db->select($field)
$result = $this->db->get('user');
```

**Method 03**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user")
$result = $query->result_array();
```

You can use any way that you like. Code will execute in all this way.

> **Note :** ***Method 01*** and ***Method 02*** from your Question and ***Method 03*** is which i used.(***Method 03*** is tested and works well)